# Extracting opening parenthesis in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to extract opening parenthesis in R. But getting the following error.

```
text = "suppressWarnings( Gauge_Rule_Extraction( machine_id, gauge_output_calculation_df, host ) )"

gregexpr( "(", text )

Error in gregexpr("(", m) : 
  invalid regular expression '(', reason 'Missing ')''
```

But I am able to extract closing parenthesis.

```
gregexpr(")", m)
[[1]]
[1] 123 125
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 1 1
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

Anything I am doing wrong.

Comment: General comment: I dont know what you plan on doing here, but if you want to handle nested parentheses, in general you would need a parser to do that, not just a regex.

Answer (score 2):

Brackets need to be escaped in regex.  This is done with a back slash.  Further, the backslase will then need to be escaped, so double up:

```
gregexpr( "\\(", text )

[[1]]
[1] 17 40
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 1 1
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```